# SQLQuery Errors

Tags: sql

Can someone assist as to what is wrong with query. Error is
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [SessionId]
WHERE [FONumber] = '156101'
AND [ShipTo] = '868257'
AND [OrderDate] = '2016-07-11'
FROM [NFConnect].[dbo].[tblOrders]
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is `select ... from ..where`:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [SessionId]
FROM [NFConnect].[dbo].[tblOrders]
WHERE [FONumber] = '156101'
AND [ShipTo] = '868257'
AND [OrderDate] = '2016-07-11'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `FROM` shoud be before the `WHERE` clauses:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [SessionId]
FROM [NFConnect].[dbo].[tblOrders]
WHERE [FONumber] = '156101'
AND [ShipTo] = '868257'
AND [OrderDate] = '2016-07-11'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `FROM` before `WHERE`

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [SessionId]
FROM [NFConnect].[dbo].[tblOrders]
WHERE [FONumber] = '156101'
AND [ShipTo] = '868257'
AND [OrderDate] = '2016-07-11'
```

You can check the syntax for t-sql here[enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx)

```
SELECT [ ALL | DISTINCT ]   
    [TOP ( expression ) [PERCENT] [ WITH TIES ] ]   
    < select_list >   
    [ INTO new_table ]   
    [ FROM { <table_source> } [ ,...n ] ]   
    [ WHERE <search_condition> ]   
    [ <GROUP BY> ]   
    [ HAVING < search_condition > ]
```